# How to rewrite url in istio virtual service

Tags: regex, kubernetes, url-rewriting, istio, istio-gateway

How can we rewrite the url in virtual service.
eg:

```
Actual url----> http//test.com/service1/v1/list
rewrite url path---->/v1/list
```

After matching the path based routing with prefix "service1", I want to remove the second value of the url, in this case "service1" and send rest of the path(/v1/list) to the destination service.

i have tried the below VS, but it didnt worked,

```
spec:
  hosts:
  - test.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /service1
    rewrite:
      uriRegexRewrite:
        match: /service1(/|$)(.*)
        rewrite: $2    
    route:
    - destination:
        host: service1.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Are there any mistakes in the "match" and "rewrite" methods for eliminating the second value from the URL while keeping the other values?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, you may try this approach:

```
apiVersion: [networking.istio.io/v1alpha3]
kind: VirtualService 
metadata: 
    name: service1-virtual-service 
spec: 
  hosts:
  - test.com 
  http:
  -match:
   - uri: 
      prefix: "/service1" 
   rewrite: 
     uri: "/v1/list" 
   route:
   - destination: 
       host: service1.default.svc.cluster.local
```

This example uses the prefix to match requests starting with /service1 and then rewrite the URI to /v1/list which is a fit for your use case.

Comment: But, I cant hardcode the /v1/list in the rewrite URI, it should be dynamic.
For example:
"Eg1:  http://test.com/service1/v1/list -----> /v1/list".
"Eg2: http://test.com/service1/map/root/get -----> map/root/get".

.Basically, once the path-based match happens, then I need to remove only the second value(here in the above example it is service1) from the URI and keep the rest of the URI path(without hardcoding).

If I can get a correct match & rewrite method to remove the second value by keeping the rest of the URI path will help.